# How to execute .cmd files as Admin by default

Tags: windows, windows-8, command-line

I created simple .cmd file:

```
sc stop audiosrv
sc start audiosrv
```

but I have to right click and "Run as Administrator" how can I set this file to run as admin by default after double left click?

Comment: create a shortcut then modify the properties.  This will still required the approval of the esclation of the process which means a UAC prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Call it with [PSEXEC](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) -h

That will work.  Other than that, you can disable UAC completely.

Answer (score 0):

Put this before your script starts:

```
@echo off

:: BatchGotAdmin
:-------------------------------------
REM  --> Check for permissions
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"
REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
echo Requesting administrative privileges...
goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )

:UACPrompt
echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
set params = %*:"=""
echo UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/c %~s0 %params%", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

"%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
exit /B

:gotAdmin
pushd "%CD%"
CD /D "%~dp0"
```